# Send SMS via Skyp API

Tags: c#, sms, skype

I have a c# app and I wish to send an sms to a specfic User whenever I have an update for that User.

I intend to have many different Users.

I heard that it is possible to send SMS via Skype.

I download some sample code but when I run it I got an error saying 'connection refused'.

I also then came across a blog stating that using Skype this way has potential errors like the SMS not getting through or taking days to get through.

I heard also that Skype are not that good with support in this area.

But, I cannot get past this error to find that all out.

If I send the sms directly using Skype's GUI/App then it comes through no problem.

So, is my code correct?
Should I use Skype for this at all?
Has anyone had a similar thing to do and has a better idea?

Thanks.

CODE:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sendNumber =  "+44-79-7059-0893";
        var msgBody = "test message";

        SendSMSMessage(sendNumber, msgBody);
    }

    void SendSMSMessage(string number, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            var skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
            skype.Timeout = 120 * 1000; 

            var smsType = SKYPE4COMLib.TSmsMessageType.smsMessageTypeOutgoing;  //error occurs here
            var message = skype.CreateSms(smsType, number);
            message.Body = body;
            message.Send();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is following this I got this response from Sjype:

Andrew,
I am guessing your talking about the Desktop API (formally Public API) which was deprecated in December 2013? I would strongly encourage you not to build on this API as anything you build will have a limited shelf life. 
Kind regards
Allen Smith
Program Manager
Skype Developer